# How to overcome `Prohibited package name` exception?

Tags: java, securityexception

Is it possible to turn off / override `java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name`?

I need to extend `AffineTransform` class which was implemented with some lack of functionality, and I need to access members `m00, m01, ...` which are defined as package protected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cant. It's hardcoded in java.lang.ClassLoader:

```
    if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
        throw new SecurityException
            ("Prohibited package name: " +
             name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

...

as you can see there is no option

Answer (score 1):

You can read the values with the [getMatrix(double[] flatmatrix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getMatrix%28double%5B%5D%29). There is no corresponding `setMatrix`, but there is the [AffineTransform(double[] flatmatrix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#AffineTransform%28double%5B%5D%29) constructor.

Out of curiosity, what is the "lack of functionality" you refer to?

**Update:**

Ah, ok. The Java2D are really just for the basic 2D transforms. For anything the involves depth you may want to take a look at some of the Java / OpenGL bindings.

- [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) - Java Open GL bindings ([JSR-231](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=231))
- [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) - Lightweight Java Game Library
- [Jave 3D](https://java3d.java.net/) - The original 3d api from Sun.

**Update 2:**

One other library to check out would be the [Java Advanced Imaging (JAI) API](https://java.net/projects/jai). The possible downside is it is not actively maintained; last updated in 2006. It's entirely focused on images, so you would need to:

- render to a `BufferedImage`
- create a `NullOpImage` from that
- `PerspectiveTransform` the `NullOpImage`
- and extract a final `BufferedImage`

Comment: I mean rational linear transform (including perspective transform). I took `PerspectiveTransform` from `JAI` and made it `extends AffineTransform` in order to code more wide range of transforms in standard `PathIterator`.

Comment: Thanks! But I want namely 2D. Also I would like to tie with AWT because I use `Piccolo2D` library which is also tied with it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Evgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19957466/58997) pointed out, the check is hard-coded in the ClassLoader, so circumventing this is no easy task. But there is always an option :-)

One could use the [Java bootclasspath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things11/) option on startup or implement a [javaagent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to slip in own improvements. The question is not whether it is doable, but whether this is the most sensible solution in terms of effort and overall maintenance.

Be aware, however, that since this introduces a potential security leak, both cannot be done for e.g. an Applet.